# Passing a pointer to QML string property to C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How do you pass a pointer to string property from QML to C++?

When I attempted to do it the obvious way, I got this error:

```
qrc:/NewAccount.qml:236: Error: Unknown method parameter type: QString*
```

Which means, QML engine can't convert `new_account.error_string` property to C++ when calling `save_account` (Q_INVOKABLE) method

This is my code in QML:

```
import myproject.aewm.ethkey 1.0
import myproject.aewm.walletaccount 1.0
...
id: new_account
property EthKey key: EthKey{}
property WalletAccount account: WalletAccount{}
property string error_string: ""
....
if (aewm_obj.save_account(key,account,new_account.error_string)) {
    wallet_accounts_tabbar.currentIndex=0
} else {
    console.log("error occurred:"+new_account.error_string)
}
```

Where `aewm_obj` is a C++ type (registered in QML) and `save_account` is declared in C++ as :

```
Q_INVOKABLE     bool save_account(EthKey *key, WalletAccount *account, QString *err_str);
```

The docs say that a (QML) `string` property is a `QString` object, and that these types are automatically converted from from C++ and QML . I am passing pointers to my custom QObject-derived classes without any problems after `qmlRegisterType()` call, so why I can't do the same with strings?

I thought that maybe string pointers are not supported and I tried to add this line:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QString*>("QString*");
```

but after this change, the pointer I received at C++ side was 0x0 and I got a segfault.

So, how do you pass pointers to QML string properties from QML to C++ ?

Or, do you think I should register `QString` class with qmlRegisterType() too? I tried it but I have encountered some compilation issues, so I think it won't compile.

The last solution would be to create a custom object with a QString inside, and send a pointer to it from QML to C++. But, this would be an overkill, if QString exists why not find a way to use it?

Will appreciate very much your comments. I definitely want to use pointers , it is safer than dealing with object ownership when exchanging data between C++ and QML.

Comment: Why do you want to spend a pointer and not just the value?

Comment: QML can only pass QObject pointers, in the case of QString only passes the copied value, why does it say that it is safer to pass pointers?

Comment: @eyllanesc, because I am returning the error , the C++ code sets the error and QML receives it

Comment: @eyllanesc, QML can pass pointers to objects, if you do `qmlRegisterType()` on an class, you can pass a pointer to its objects from QML to C++ without any problem. I am doing this all the time. But it only works with my custom classes, it doesn't work with `QString`. But why ? Is there a way to make `QString` pointers to work like other class pointers?

Comment: `qmlRegisterType()` works only with `QObject` subclasses, and `QString` ain't that. And it is only so that you can create the objects declaratively. Regular `QObject`s can be perfectly accessed from QML without registering. And `QString` is already automatically converted to a `string` on the QML side. Supporting `QObject`s via pointers is just an auxiliary, it doesn't mean QML supports pointers, it does not.

Comment: @dtech, ok, very clear answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, QML only passes pointers from the `QObject`s, and `QString` is not a `QObject`.

I think you are giving an incorrect approach to the problem, you could create a property in the object that performs the calculations that have the error message as shown below.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

class Foo: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString errorMessage READ errorMessage)
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    Q_INVOKABLE bool process(int a, int b, int res){
        bool status;
        // some operation
        status = (a+b) == res;
        mErrorMessage = status? "": QString("error message: %1 + %2 is different to %3").arg(a).arg(b).arg(res);
        return status;
    }
    QString errorMessage() const{
        return mErrorMessage;
    }

private:
    QString mErrorMessage;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Foo>("com.eyllanesc.org", 1, 0, "Foo");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

import com.eyllanesc.org 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Foo{ id: foo }

    Row{
        SpinBox{ id: a }
        SpinBox{ id: b }
        SpinBox{ id: c }

        Button{
            text: "process"
            onClicked: {
                var message;
                if(foo.process(a.value, b.value, c.value)){
                    message = "correct"
                    console.log("successful")
                }
                else{
                    message = foo.errorMessage
                    console.log("error is "+ message)
                }
                txt.text = message
            }
        }
        Label{ id: txt }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I wanted to take a "shortcut" , but seems that this is the only way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Nulik Maybe it's a shortcut in C ++, for my liking it's not :) because it makes it less readable, but since QML does not handle the pointers, except QObjects.

Comment: It is perfectly legal to pass pointers around in QML, after all, a pointer is just an integer in practice. However, QML doesn't provide the facilities to acquire pointers to objects, save for `QObject` derived objects via their lexical references (ids, property names, parent, this, etc). You can't just willinilly  acquire pointers to this and that, besides the fact that data transfer between QML and C++ involves conversion and the objects at both sides are not even in the same binary format, and the QtQuick data representation is fundamentally different paradigm from C++.

Comment: @dtech That's what I meant, maybe I do not use the correct words.

Answer (score 1):

With Qt, the C++ API and the QML API are completely different, and practically incompatible layers. There is a lot of conversion of data back and forth in order to make the whole thing work. And you don't really have control over it when it comes to primitives like strings. So just get that idea out of your head.

If you want to access a particular property of a particular object, you need to pass the object that will be received as a pointer, and the property name, which then you can access via its name string via `QObject`s `property()` and `setProperty()`.

But in your case that is entirely redundant, simply pass the string itself.